# How do i know a contact was created or updated using google people api?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I'm using the google people API for independent projects and I came across the following issue, when I get the contacts that were created or updated after the last syncToken I can't tell if they were actually created or updated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're syncing a set of contacts in your app with the set of contacts stored in Google Contacts,
then you can compare the contacts received from the People API with the contacts already existing in your app, all the contacts in the response that don't exist in your app were created since your last sync.